# Getting SSR to work with the React Context API

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-context

Basically we have a module that reads the client data on server side render and is supposed to provide the data to the renderToString with the data it found (and the client renders with a `window.__SOME_DATA__`, but I would not want to use a global on a express route)

Here is where we are:

```
const contentService = new ServerService();
const app = (
  <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
    <App/>
  </StaticRouter>
);

try {
  await contentService.getSomeData(app);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('THERE WAS A MARKUP ERROR', error);
}

const markup = renderToString(
  contentService.withProvider(
    app
  )
);
```

The server service looks like so:

```
export class ServerService {
  items = {};

  getSomeData = async (app) => {
    // gets some server side data and saves it to the `items` object
  };

  withProvider = (app) => {
    const providedApp = (
      <ServerProvider data={this.items}>
        { app }
      </ServerProvider>
    );

    console.log('ITEMS provided', { data: this.items });

    return providedApp;
  };

  getScriptData() {
    return `
      <script>
          window. __SOME_DATA__ = ${JSON.stringify(this.items)};
      </script>
    `;
  }
}
```

And then last but not least my provider:

```
import * as React from 'react';

const ServerContext = React.createContext(null);

export class ServerProvider extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log('Providing data', { props: this.props });

    return (
      <ServerContext.Provider value={{ ...this.props.data }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ServerContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
export const ServerConsumer = ServerContext.Consumer;
```

The problem is that it seems to set the data in the `withProvider` function fine, but when I use the `ServerConsumer` component, it seems to contain **nothing** -- but it *should* contain the data that was passed to the provider!

The context api has worked beautifully for when I need it on the client side, but it seems to be failing for me on the server side.

This is with react/react-dom `16.4.1`

---

Updates after comment, here is how I am using the consumer:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ServerConsumer } from "./serverContext";
import { ContentStateProvider } from "./ContentStateProvider";

const renderChildrenWithServerData = (props) => (state, ...rest) => {
  console.log({ state, props, rest }, 'I AM DATA', ServerConsumer);

  return (
    <ContentStateProvider currentState={state} {...props} />
  );
};

export class ContentProvider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // console.log({ Consumer }, 'CONTEXT is cool');
    return (
      <ServerConsumer>{renderChildrenWithServerData(this.props)}</ServerConsumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the value you are able to get inside ServerConsumer. ANd one more thing Could you please tell how you are importing ServerConsumer in your respective file

Comment: @stack26 Updated the OP for you.

I get no data in the consumer.

Comment: See related react github issue I created after I created this question: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13251

Comment: Interesting logic. Do you have a full snipped with the client code as well? And what do you mean with "and the client renders with a window.__SOME_DATA__, but I would not want to use a global on a express route"

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work @NaftaliakaNeal.  I am facing same issue in my SSR app. Context is fine on server side, but on client side, it takes default value (null or any other default value we set).

Comment: for anyone else facing this issue it looks to be a false alarm: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13251

Answer (score -1):

Mentioning it here because, difficult to all code in comments
The value passed as through context is accessed in this way

```
<ServerConsumer>{(value) => { console.log(value)}}</ServerConsumer>
```

Your Consumer Version is :

```
<ServerConsumer>
  {renderChildrenWithServerData(this.props)}
</ServerConsumer>
```

renderChildrenWithServerData(this.props) return a stateless components. You need to retrieve the Context data at the level mentioned below to pass it on to renderChildrenWithServerData

```
<ServerConsumer>
   {(value) => {
     return renderChildrenWithServerData(value, this.props)
   }}
</ServerConsumer>
```

Comment: `renderChildrenWithServerData` returns a function which consumes the data.

Comment: my bad !! I missed that. But the way you are accessing context value looks incorrect. let me edit the answer

Comment: oook let me know :-)

Comment: You did not change anything...

The way I am currently using the consumer is correct as `renderChildrenWithServerData` returns a function that utilizes the consumer data

Comment: Where you are picking up context data. I am unable to understand. Sorry. Could you please tell?

Comment: Yeah i understood, i think there is some other problem which i am unable to see!!